# HTML viewport meta starts from specific width

Tags: html, width, viewport, meta

I'd like to ask you if there is any possibility to run  from a specific width... for example I want to do something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" start_from="width=500px" content="width-device-width">
```

If there is a possibility I would appreciate if you post it here. Thank you for help.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Maybe there's a better method.

Comment: Well I want to have responsive site from specific width..  for example when somebody is on my webpage from desktop PC I don't want the site to be responsive, but when somebody is on my webpage from phone or netbook I'd like to made viewport for width-devide-width, so that means my page would be responsive. I don't mean it like the final decision, I'm just experimenting and learning new things and it's interesting for me, maybe it would look nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a [`@media tag and css`](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

You put meta viewport according divice width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">
```

and, then adjust the size for the panel attached to the viewPort:
For example:

you can sent the styles for content on screens that have a width of 480px and lower.

```
 @media all and (max-width: 480px) {
      // styles assigned when width is smaller than 480px;
 }
```

[Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Hope that will helps you to achieve your task.

Comment: I'll try it, thank you. But isn't the whole page responsive then ? Or it is resposive only from the width , as in example, 480px ?

Comment: Here you need to define different - 2 media rules for different - 2 widths. Note:CSS media-query works like a if-else statements. Please read this one: http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries

Comment: Your welcome. You can up-vote answer, if it's helpful to you..:)

Comment: I will.. I just need to get 15 rep first ;)